# How to fix strange x axis values in ACF and PACF plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I was trying to adjust the data from this repo: 
[Forcasting A Time Series Stock Market Data](https://github.com/Stat-Wizards/Forcasting-A-Time-Series-Stock-Market-Data) , when I noticed that the x axis values went from 0 to 1e5.

The original code produced values from 1 to 30 for lags in the ACF and PACF plots. All I did was to standardize the price by doing:

```
GSPC<-as.xts(apply(GSPC, 2, function(x) x / x[1]))
```

Trying: GSPC<-as.xts(apply(GSPC$GSPC.Close, 2, function(x) x / x[1](https://github.com/Stat-Wizards/Forcasting-A-Time-Series-Stock-Market-Data))) gets the same result.

Edit 1: Trying @jay.sf suggestion:

```
scale=GSPC$GSPC.Close[1]
GSPC<-scale(GSPC$GSPC.Close,center=FALSE,scale=scale)
```

and the x axis goes back to having 30 lags.

```
# Libraries
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
library(rugarch)
library(prophet)
library(tsfknn)
rm(list=ls())
getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo",from="2015-01-01",to = "2020-06-04")
#GSPC<-as.xts(apply(GSPC, 2, function(x) x / x[1]))
date = index(GSPC)
date = as.Date(date)
head(GSPC)
chartSeries(GSPC,TA = NULL)
chartSeries(GSPC,TA=c(addVo(),addBBands(),addMACD()))
print(adf.test(GSPC$GSPC.Close))
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
acf(GSPC$GSPC.Close)
pacf(GSPC$GSPC.Close)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: Have you tried `GSPC <- scale(GSPC)` instead of your `apply` approach?

Comment: no, the y axis is fine. the x axis is hosed. i can't see how scale would help.

Comment: but it does fix the problem: 

scale=GSPC$GSPC.Close[1]
GSPC<-scale(GSPC$GSPC.Close,center=FALSE,scale=scale) and the 30 lags on the x axis come back.

Comment: Yes, I saw that when I tried your code, although I'm not sure exactly what you're doing since it's not my field.

Comment: just trying to have all of the stock prices start at 1 so the returns  are comparable.  have no clue why x axis gets hosed.